# Unit tests : cohabitation of the production-code and the mocked implementation

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I know about the basics about test doubles, mocking, etc. but I'm having problems to test the following

```
void funA(void) {
    /* do some stuff, using mocked functions from 3rd party library */
}
```

I've written the unit tests for `funA()`, checking the good functions were called (using their mocked implementation).
So far, the mocked functions are library functions. This is not my code. I don't want to test their original implementation.

Now, I want to test this function

```
void funB(void) {
    /* do some complicated stuff, and call `funA()` on some situations */
}
```

How can I be sure my `funA` function was called from `funB`? I can't add a fake implementation to `funA`, I need its production code so it can be tested.

What I am doing now is making sure the mocks that `funA` is calling are as I expect them to be. But it's not a good method, because it's like I'm testing `funA` all over again, when I just want to make sure `funB` does its job.

Comment: It's unclear (to me at least) neither what you want nor what the problem is..

Comment: I agree with @EugeneSh. Before asking, you should understand yourself what the problem is. Just that: to test `funB, you can write another testing function `funC`. It's lurtles all the way down ...

Comment: When you test `funA`, stub out its dependencies. When you test `funB`, stub out its dependencies (`funA`). You shouldn't need `funA`'s production code in `funB`'s test - you're testing `funB`, not `funA`.

Comment: And pikc **one** language. C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: But how can I stub `funA` here? I have only one test executable, and in this executable I need `funA` implementation.
The only way I see is to use function pointers when I call `funA` (in my test code... and my production code). But I don't want to do that...

Comment: The same way you're currently mocking functions called from `funA`. If that approach doesn't scale, you can go the traditional route of interfaces or use something like a tagged `std::function` for dependencies, or untagged if that suits you better.

Comment: This is the thing. I am not testing the functions called from `funA`, they are library function, that I've stubbed to spy on them.
But I don't know how to do to have the production implementation and a stub implementation at the same time for `funA` (or any other functions for that matter)

Comment: So rather than having test doubles of those functions, you're actually replacing them unconditionally is what I'm getting from that. Regardless, C++ supports OOP and that's probably a good place to start considering it's probably the most prominent method of dependency injection and whatnot. I started making a little library for better DI with functions rather than entire classes, but that's nowhere near public yet. Using interfaces and implementation classes is pretty straightforward. For more advanced C techniques, perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmy6g-aVgZI

Comment: Consider using a separate unit test executable for each function under test.  This is the cleanest way to approach the problem.

Comment: @chris i'm gonna watch the video and see if i find solutions there, cheers

Comment: @JohnBollinger But this is an insane solution, no? I am at the start of my project and have already 75 tests, I would have to generate 75 executables, I feel that this solution is going to bring a lot of complexity.

Comment: @rtur, no, it is not insane at all.  It is pragmatic -- how can you properly unit test a given function if you do not isolate it?  Building and executing all these tests should be no particular problem for `make`, or for your alternative build system of choice (if indeed such a system is worth using).  Indeed, I maintain a C project whose 70 tests are structured just this way.

Comment: @rtur, note that you can get a great deal of reuse out of your stubs.  You probably don't need separate stubs per test; compile them separately and link them to the function under test.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will give it more thought. Maybe it is not the worst idea, and it scares me a bit. I feel like we are reaching the point where tests are getting in way instead of helping me being productive. But maybe I'm just getting scared of the unknown.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more understandable. Please let me know if it still does not make any sense!

Comment: @rtur, it is not uncommon for a thorough test suite to be as large as the code under test.  In that sense, yes, maintaining it can be a burden.  On the other hand, how can you be confident that your code works as intended without tests?  Manual testing just isn't feasible for any but the very smallest programs, and doing without tests is a non-starter.  Every time my tests alert me to a regression I've accidentally introduced, I am very thankful to have written them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger See my answer for the question. It does seem your solution is actually a good one. Thanks for your inputs, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it (see the comments of the original question), and having a brief forum exchange with James Grenning (one of the author of CppUTest), the main solutions are the following:

- Having different test builds for `funA()` and `funB()`
- Using function pointers to dynamically change the behaviour

I'm not a huge fan of either of the solutions, but it feels like I can't do much more in C. I will eventually go for the multiple binaries solution.

For reference, here is the answer of James Grennings:

> You may want to mock A() when testing B().
>
> for example
>
> If I have a message_dispatcher() that reads a command from a serial
>   port via getline(), and getline() uses getc() and getc() uses IORead
>   and IOWrite. I could mock IORead and IOWrite and have a set of
>   horrible tests to test the message_dispatcher().
>
> Or I could test getc() with mock IORead() and IOWrite(), getline()
>   with some kind of fake_getc(), and test message_dispatcher() with
>   fake_getline(). If you only use linker substitution, you would need
>   three tests builds. If you used function pointers you could do one
>   test build. You can mix an match too.
>
> getc() should be tested with link time mocks of IORead and IOWrite
>   because your unit tests never want the real IORead and IOWrite for
>   off-target tests (they may be needed of on-target tests, but those
>   would be integration tests).
>
> There are many possibilities. You could also have some other code
>   getline() and feed it to the dispatcher, removing its dependencies.